# Ubuntu 18.04 - Mount NFS with FQDN not resolving address

Tags: 18.04, fstab, nfs

Trying to mount */home* directories to a NFS share.

```
SERVERURL:/nfstest    /home    nfs    vers=4,proto=tcp,intr,bg,rdirplus        0 0
```

However, in *syslog* it says that it cannot resolve the address. I'm guessing it'll be OK if I used an IP Address, however this is not feasible due to our storage solution (IP addresses could change at a given moment).

If I mount manually with above in my *fstab* with the command:

```
mount -a
```

It manages to mount fine.

I've also tried creating a *systemd* service that will do the `mount -a` command after network is up, but i still get the same problem.

Tried numerous different mounting options, including *_netdev*.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 18.04 resolves addresses with systemd-resolved  listening on 127.0.0.53:53 (see `netstat -antup`. And resolved get his forwarder from the NetworkManager active profile. See `cat /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf` and `cat /var/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`... I guess that dns resolution is not ready when the mount command starts.

Comment: If you're willing to have the systemd service run the `mount -a` command, add a dependency (Wants/After) for `network-online.target` or `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` or similar, at which point nameserver configurations should be working. If hosting DNS you may also want to wait on bind9.service ...  See this answer in Unix SE for more details or suggestions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126146/18866

Answer (score 0):

To delay nfs mount until newtork is ready, add _netdev to option in the relevant entry in /etc/fstab. Like:

```
SERVERURL:/nfstest  /home nfs  vers=4,proto=tcp,intr,bg,rdirplus,_netdev  0 0
```

From mount(8) manpage:

```
_netdev The filesystem resides on a device that requires network access
(used to prevent the system from attempting to mount these filesystems 
until the network has been enabled on the system).
```